# IBM Notes - Formula Language - Column Value from Checkbox Field

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a checkbox field. I want to display the values from that field in a column view. The values in the field are names such as John Doe Smith. When there are multiple values in the checkbox they are displayed in an awkward manner. For instance

John Doe Smith,Jane Doe Smith,Mary Doe Smith

I want to remove the commas and replace them with a "comma space" so they are more readable. The above example should look like this

John Doe Smith, Jane Doe Smith, Mary Doe Smith

I've tried using @Replace and @ReplaceSubstring along with @Text, @Explode, @Implode, etc but I can't get the desired result.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Robin-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Implode](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_IMPLODE.html) is the way to go. Your column formula is then:

```
@Implode(YourCheckBoxField; ", ")
```

Comment: Thank you Rubens, I already had that setting in place. And THANK YOU Knut, that was it. I had been dancing all around @Implode when it was the answer all along.

Answer (score 0):

In the column properties, in the second tab, select the option "Show multiple values in separate entries"
Sorry for the English, I'm using google translate

Comment: Is this an answer, feels like a comment